# How to generate "inner shape" of 2D concave polygon?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, 2d

I have a list of 2d points which is a closed loop, 2D, concave polygon.

I want to generate a second polygon, which is fully inside the first polygon and each vertex/edge of the first polygon has a constant distance to each vertex/edge of the second polygon.

Basically, the first polygon would be "outer wall" and the second would be "inner wall", with the distance between two walls constant.

How to do something like that?

Comment: This is called an *offset* polygon and is a pretty difficult construction, because self-intersections arise. Have a look at Clipper. http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php

Comment: Note that either the distance of the *vertices* **or** the distance of the *edges* may be constant. You cannot have both at the same time. In my answer, I assumed that the distance between the *edges* ("walls") should be constant.

Answer (score 4):

For the case that you do not care about self-intersections, the construction is pretty straightforward:

For each vertex of the polygon:

- Take the previous and next line segment
- Compute the normals of these line segments
- Shift the line segments along the normal
- Compute the intersection of the shifted line segments

Below is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) implemented in Java/Swing. The actual computation takes place in `computeOffsetPolygonPoints`, and it should be easy to translate this to other languages and APIs.

[image: OffsetPolygon]

For the case that you also have to handle self-intersections, things might become trickier. Then it would be necessary to define the intended result, particularly for the case that *the polygon itself* self-intersects...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InnerPolygonShape
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        InnerPolygonShapePanel innerPolygonShapePanel = 
            new InnerPolygonShapePanel();
        JSlider offsetSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 40);
        offsetSlider.addChangeListener(e -> 
        {
            double alpha = offsetSlider.getValue() / 100.0;
            double offset = -50.0 + alpha * 100.0;
            innerPolygonShapePanel.setOffset(offset);
        });

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(innerPolygonShapePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getContentPane().add(offsetSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class InnerPolygonShapePanel extends JPanel 
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private final List<Point2D> points;
    private Point2D draggedPoint;
    private double offset = -10.0;

    public InnerPolygonShapePanel()
    {
        this.points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

        points.add(new Point2D.Double(132,532));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(375,458));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(395,267));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(595,667));

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void setOffset(double offset)
    {
        this.offset = offset;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint(g, points);

        List<Point2D> offsetPolygonPoints = 
            computeOffsetPolygonPoints(points, offset);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint(g, offsetPolygonPoints);

    }


    private static void paint(Graphics2D g, List<Point2D> points)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            int i0 = i;
            int i1 = (i + 1) % points.size();
            Point2D p0 = points.get(i0);
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i1);
            g.draw(new Line2D.Double(p0, p1));
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            double r = 5;
            g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX()-r, p.getY()-r, r+r, r+r));
        }

    }

    private static List<Point2D> computeOffsetPolygonPoints(
        List<Point2D> points, double offset)
    {
        List<Point2D> result = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        Point2D absoluteLocation = new Point2D.Double();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            // Consider three consecutive points (previous, current, next)
            int ip = (i - 1 + points.size()) % points.size();
            int ic = i;
            int in = (i + 1) % points.size();
            Point2D pp = points.get(ip);
            Point2D pc = points.get(ic);
            Point2D pn = points.get(in);

            // Compute the line segments between the previous and the current
            // point, and the current and the next point, and compute their
            // normal
            Point2D line0 = difference(pc, pp);
            Point2D direction0 = normalize(line0);
            Point2D normal0 = rotateCw(direction0);

            Point2D line1 = difference(pn, pc);
            Point2D direction1 = normalize(line1);
            Point2D normal1 = rotateCw(direction1);

            // Shift both line segments along the normal
            Point2D segment0p0 = add(pp, offset, normal0);
            Point2D segment0p1 = add(pc, offset, normal0);
            Point2D segment1p0 = add(pc, offset, normal1);
            Point2D segment1p1 = add(pn, offset, normal1);

            // Compute the intersection between the shifted line segments
            intersect(
                segment0p0.getX(), segment0p0.getY(),
                segment0p1.getX(), segment0p1.getY(),
                segment1p0.getX(), segment1p0.getY(),
                segment1p1.getX(), segment1p1.getY(),
                null, absoluteLocation);

            result.add(new Point2D.Double(
                absoluteLocation.getX(), absoluteLocation.getY()));
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (draggedPoint != null)
        {
            draggedPoint.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        final double thresholdSquared = 10 * 10;
        Point2D p = e.getPoint();
        Point2D closestPoint = null;
        double minDistanceSquared = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            double dd = point.distanceSq(p);
            if (dd < thresholdSquared && dd < minDistanceSquared)
            {
                minDistanceSquared = dd;
                closestPoint = point;
            }
        }
        draggedPoint = closestPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
    }


    private static Point2D difference(Point2D p0, Point2D p1)
    {
        double dx = p0.getX() - p1.getX();
        double dy = p0.getY() - p1.getY();
        return new Point2D.Double(dx, dy);
    }

    private static Point2D add(Point2D p0, double factor, Point2D p1)
    {
        double x0 = p0.getX();
        double y0 = p0.getY();
        double x1 = p1.getX();
        double y1 = p1.getY();
        return new Point2D.Double(x0 + factor * x1, y0 + factor * y1);
    }

    private static Point2D rotateCw(Point2D p)
    {
        return new Point2D.Double(p.getY(), -p.getX());
    }

    private static Point2D normalize(Point2D p)
    {
        double x = p.getX();
        double y = p.getY();
        double length = Math.hypot(x, y);
        return new Point2D.Double(x / length, y / length);
    }


    // From https://github.com/javagl/Geom/blob/master/src/main/java/
    // de/javagl/geom/Intersections.java

    private static final double DOUBLE_EPSILON = 1e-6;

    /**
     * Computes the intersection of the specified lines.
     * 
     * Ported from 
     * http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/
     *     Wm5IntrSegment2Segment2.cpp
     * 
     * @param s0x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s1x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param relativeLocation Optional location that stores the 
     * relative location of the intersection point on 
     * the given line segments
     * @param absoluteLocation Optional location that stores the 
     * absolute location of the intersection point
     * @return Whether the lines intersect
     */
    public static boolean intersect( 
        double s0x0, double s0y0,
        double s0x1, double s0y1,
        double s1x0, double s1y0,
        double s1x1, double s1y1,
        Point2D relativeLocation,
        Point2D absoluteLocation)
    {
        double dx0 = s0x1 - s0x0;
        double dy0 = s0y1 - s0y0;
        double dx1 = s1x1 - s1x0;
        double dy1 = s1y1 - s1y0;

        double invLen0 = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(dx0*dx0+dy0*dy0); 
        double invLen1 = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1); 

        double dir0x = dx0 * invLen0;
        double dir0y = dy0 * invLen0;
        double dir1x = dx1 * invLen1;
        double dir1y = dy1 * invLen1;

        double dot = dotPerp(dir0x, dir0y, dir1x, dir1y);
        if (Math.abs(dot) > DOUBLE_EPSILON)
        {
            if (relativeLocation != null || absoluteLocation != null)
            {
                double c0x = s0x0 + dx0 * 0.5;
                double c0y = s0y0 + dy0 * 0.5;
                double c1x = s1x0 + dx1 * 0.5;
                double c1y = s1y0 + dy1 * 0.5;

                double cdx = c1x - c0x;
                double cdy = c1y - c0y;

                double dot0 = dotPerp(cdx, cdy, dir0x, dir0y);
                double dot1 = dotPerp(cdx, cdy, dir1x, dir1y);
                double invDot = 1.0/dot;
                double s0 = dot1*invDot;
                double s1 = dot0*invDot;
                if (relativeLocation != null)
                {
                    double n0 = (s0 * invLen0) + 0.5;
                    double n1 = (s1 * invLen1) + 0.5;
                    relativeLocation.setLocation(n0, n1);
                }
                if (absoluteLocation != null)
                {
                    double x = c0x + s0 * dir0x;
                    double y = c0y + s0 * dir0y;
                    absoluteLocation.setLocation(x, y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the perpendicular dot product, i.e. the length
     * of the vector (x0,y0,0)x(x1,y1,0).
     * 
     * @param x0 Coordinate x0
     * @param y0 Coordinate y0
     * @param x1 Coordinate x1
     * @param y1 Coordinate y1
     * @return The length of the cross product vector
     */
    private static double dotPerp(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
    {
        return x0*y1 - y0*x1;
    }    

}
```